# Why is PHP execution stopping after a script is included?

Tags: php, include, execution

I have the following code I use to call a script on demand:

```
<?php
include '../includes/header.php';

// Runs whitelist cron
echo "Rebuild latest reviews include file...";
include 'cron_dp_top10.php';
echo "Done!<br>";

echo "Please wait... Redirecting to CAMDB Index page...";

sleep(15);
?>
<script>
window.location.href='index.php';
</script>
<?php 
include '../includes/footer.php';
?>
```

The page is only displaying to the "include 'cron_dp_top10.php';" line. So it seems like it is stopping on the page include somehow.

However, the included script is executing with no issues all the way through the end. It makes me think there is an issue with the last bit of code the included script runs which is the following:

```
// Update permissions on static files in directory
$dh = dir ("$path/CAMDB/static/wb");
while ($entry = $dh->read()) {
    chmod ($entry, 0755); 
}
$dh->close();
```

It makes it seem like there's something with the directory read that is stopping the parent script from continuing. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get an error in your server log? It could be the script doesn't have permission to change permissions of files (likely). Though that should generate warnings rather than stop the script entirely.

Comment: Actually, this was it. For some reason I missed the errors, but when I went digging I found them. If you want to add an answer, I can mark yours as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cfreak's comment sent me in the right direction. The script was kicking a permissions error on the logs. Writing this so I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: the first two entries in

```
$dir->read()
```

are

```
.
..
```

might be, the 2nd entry (..) causes your problems?